# Quadratic residue definition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition, quadratic-residues

Why quadratic residue $\pmod n$ must be, by definition, relatively prime with $n$? So, for example $5$ is not quadratic residue modulo $10$? This seems unnatural. Any help?

Comment: Who says $5$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod 10$?

Comment: $4$ is a quadratic residue mod $10$, but it isn't coprime with $10$.

Comment: I like the distinction between *quadratic residue modulo $n$* and *square modulo $n$*.

Comment: @RobArthan Is $5$ a quadratic residue modulo $5$?

Comment: This to a large degree a matter of convenience/convention.  For example zero is not a quadratic residue by the usual definition, even though $0^2\equiv 0 \bmod n$.   Omitting these cases helps to simplify statement of quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: @AnginaSeng:I don't see the relevance of your comment - other than the somewhat pedantic point that I should perhaps have said that $[4]$ is a quadratic residue mod $10$.

Comment: @RobArthan Would you say that $[5]$ is a quadratic residue modulo $5$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue, yes it is. What is the point of your comments?

Comment: @RobArthan And according to Hardy and Wright it isn't. What is the point of your comments?

Comment: For example, number theorist, Andrej Dujella, wrote a book (*Teorija brojeva*). In chapter about quadratic residues definition of quadratic residue is: *"Let $gcd(a, m) = 1.$ If congruence $x^2 \equiv a \pmod m$ has a solution, we say that $a$ is quadratic residue modulo $m$. If not, we say that $a$ is quadratic nonresidue modulo $m$. Notice that quadratic residue and quadratic nonresidue are define only if $gcd(a, m) = 1.$"*

Comment: @AnginaSeng: the point of my comments was to elucidate what definition of quadratic residue the OP was using. It is true that Hardy and Wright introduce their definition of quadratic residue in the case when $n$ is an odd prime. Apparently the OP is using a text that imposes a slightly looser restriction. I don't think either of these restrictions is commonplace in current practice and think it is bizarre to assert that $4$ and $5$ are not quadratic residues mod $10$: $2^2 = 4$ and $5^2 = 25$ after all.

Comment: I find it bizarre that someone finds it bizarre for a text to use the natural extension of the established notion for primes.

Comment: So there is no clear definition of this basic concept? I think that this strange definition (gcd) is motivated by modulo some prime $p \geq 3$ where, of course, all quadratic residues ($\neq 0$) are relatively prime with $p$. But, in the end, it is one clumsy definition.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: can you please give a clear exposition of why you find the Wikipedia's definition of quadratic residue to be incorrect, with references. And then, perhaps, contribute to the community by correcting the Wikipedia page so that it embraces the alternative definitions that you favour.

Comment: @RobArthan See lhf's answer. Virtually all texts on number theory insist that a quadratic residue modulo a prime $p$ is a number **not** divisible by $p$ which is a square modulo $p$; Wikipedia is the outlier here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two concepts here, hence two names:

- quadratic residue modulo $n$  = square in the group of units mod $n$
- square modulo $n$ = square in the ring of integers mod $n$

It seems the first one occurs more often.

Comment: However, Wikipedia does not agree with that definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

Comment: This seems ok, but still. Name is quadratic **residue**. So, this elimination is complitely wrong, that's for sure. This is one of thing that makes math definitions or notation complicated (for example $\sin^2{x} = (\sin{x})^2, (\forall x \in \mathbb{R})$ but $f^{- 1}(x) \neq \frac{1}{f(x)}$ (for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$). So healthy notation would be $\sin^2{x} = \sin{(\sin{x})}$.

Comment: @Ihf, and also check this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticResidue.html. Nonsensical confusion...

Comment: Note that the Wikipedia article has an explicit disclaimer: "Although it makes things tidier, this article does not insist that residues must be coprime to the modulus."  So the Reader is put on notice about the alternative definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Some authors include this requirement while others don’t. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#History,_conventions,_and_elementary_facts), for instance, doesn’t, but mentions this convention and explains why some authors adopt it:

> Modulo a prime, the product of two nonresidues is a residue and the product of a nonresidue and a (nonzero) residue is a nonresidue. [...] Modulo a composite number, the product of two residues is a residue. The product of a residue and a nonresidue may be a residue, a nonresidue, or zero. [...] Also, the product of two nonresidues may be either a residue, a nonresidue, or zero. This phenomenon can best be described using the vocabulary of abstract algebra. The congruence classes relatively prime to the modulus are a group under multiplication, called the group of units of the ring $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$, and the squares are a subgroup of it. Different nonresidues may belong to different cosets, and there is no simple rule that predicts which one their product will be in. Modulo a prime, there is only the subgroup of squares and a single coset.
>
> The fact that, e.g., modulo $15$ the product of the nonresidues $3$ and $5$, or of the nonresidue $5$ and the residue $9$, or the two residues $9$ and $10$ are all zero comes from working in the full ring $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$, which has zero divisors for composite $n$.
>
> For this reason some authors add to the definition that a quadratic residue $a$ must not only be a square but must also be relatively prime to the modulus $n$.

One instance where you can see how adding this requirement can simplify things is the interpretation of the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol). The image caption in that article states that “if $k$ is a quadratic residue modulo a coprime $n$, then $\left(\frac kn\right)=1$”. If the coprimality requirement is included in the definition, this statement simplifies to “if $k$ is a quadratic residue, then $\left(\frac kn\right)=1$”.